# Jenkins - execute curl command with options from multi-line parameter

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job with multi-line parameter:

```
parameters {
  text name: 'CURL_OPTIONS', defaultValue: '', description: 'The curl options and parameters.'
}
```

I'm trying to execute curl command with given parameter, for example:

```
--location 'https://ifconfig.io' \
 --header 'header1: X' \
 --header 'header2: Y' \
 --header 'header3: Z' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{
     "data": {
         "app": "X",
         "countryRegion": "EN"
     }
 }'
```

which comes from Postman code snippet.

In the jenkinsfile I have:

```
sh '''
  curl $CURL_OPTIONS
'''
```

But it does not work:

```
curl: (1) Protocol 'https not supported or disabled in libcurl
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: X'; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Y'; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Z'; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "data"; Unknown error
 curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "app"; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "X",; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "countryRegion"; Unknown error
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "EN"; Unknown error
 curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
 curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
```

It also does not work even if pass tr command to remove backslash and '\n':

```
curl $( echo $CURL_OPTIONS | tr -d '\n\\' )
```

It is familiar to this:

```
$ cat curl_options1.txt | tr -d '\n\\'
--location 'https://ifconfig.io'  --header 'header1: X'  --header 'header2: Y'  --header 'header3: Z'  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  --data-raw '{     "data": {         "app": "X",         "countryRegion": "EN"     } }'

$ curl $(cat curl_options1.txt | tr -d '\n\\' )
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: X'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Y'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Z'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
```

Of course it works from command line:

```
$ curl --location 'https://ifconfig.io' \
  --header 'header1: X' \
  --header 'header2: Y' \
  --header 'header3: Z' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
      "data": {
          "app": "X",
          "countryRegion": "EN"
      }
  }'
404 page not found
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How to do it properly?

Comment: This probably needs to be interpolated in Groovy instead of the shell interpreter. Try `sh "curl ${params.CURL_OPTIONS}"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The multiline string from the parameter can be used as an argument to the Jenkins Pipeline shell step method, but the interpolation must occur within the pipeline as a Groovy variable, and not within the shell interpreter as a shell variable. Then the multiline strings will be delimited correctly by the shell interpreter. Changing the step to:

```
sh "curl ${params.CURL_OPTIONS}"
```

will cause this desired behavior.

Comment: This is good solution but it generates next problem. The CURL_OPTIONS should contains only data for curl, but it can also contains for example " | rm -rf *".

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation

Comment: Is there Perl taint mode equivalent for Jenkins pipeline?